# Auto Select / Set a value of editorparams values

Tags: javascript, tabulator

We are using Tablulator v4.6.3 for creating an interface in **one page** with the table and having one field is to make a selection by the user from the list of values like below.

**editor: "select", editorParams: { values: ["Start", "Draft", "Save", "Submit", "Close"] }**

In another **page**, we are displaying these saved data to allow modifications for these earlier selected values, how do we make these selected values are selected automatically in the column and allowed for further selection (to modify existing selection).

As a test , we are setting this values statically using below

**rowFormatter: function (row) { row.getCell("status").setValue('Draft'); },**

but if fails some way and shows errors in browser with this test code.

Can anyone please help us on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone please help us.

Comment: Is there any existing way to do this or didn't exist in Tabulator ?

Comment: please post a link to a JS Fiddle or Codepen that demonstrates your issue, it is hard to offer advice without seing the context of your table setup

Comment: as an aside you should not be updating any row values in the row formatter, it will likely result in a code loop that will crash the browser.

Comment: Im afraid i dont understand what you are asking for in your second paragraph, please look at the description and see if you can make it clearer

Comment: Modified description.

Comment: Found solution for this problem, anyhow. Solution is straight forward i.e. binding the same value which was set in the create page.                                                                                                    columns: [
             
                  {
                      title: "Status", field: "Status", width: 210, cssClass: "blue-background", editor: "select", editorParams:
                        { values:["Start", "Draft", "Save", "Submit", "Close"] },

Comment: Thanks for your attention in helping us:)